# Не получается присвоить значение перемменой unity mirror

Tags: c#, unity3d, online

у меня есть 3 метода и ни один не может изменить перемменую isSpawned на true. в начале запускается cmdSetTeam(true)

```
[Command]
public void CmdSetTeam(bool TTeam)
{
    if (isT == TTeam && isSpawned)
        return;
    else if (TTeam && _TPlayerCount < _CTPlayerCount)
        return;
    else if (!TTeam && _TPlayerCount > _CTPlayerCount)
        return;
    else
    {
        if (TTeam)
            _TPlayerCount++;
        else
            _CTPlayerCount++;

        Debug.Log("isSpawned");
        isT = TTeam;
        isAlive = true;
        isSpawned = true;
        transform.position = GameManager.Singleton.GetStartPosition(TTeam);
        SetGmPlayerData();
    }
}


[Server]
public void SetGmPlayerData()
{
    Debug.Log(isSpawned);

    _myMeshRenderer.enabled = isAlive && (!isLocalPlayer || isUsesMap);
    _myCollider.enabled = isAlive;
    _myRb.isKinematic = !isAlive;

    RpcSetGmPlayerData(isT, isAlive, isSpawned, hp);
}

[ClientRpc]
private void RpcSetGmPlayerData(bool _isT, bool _isAlive, bool _isSpawned, int _hp)
{
    Debug.Log(isSpawned);
    isT = _isT;
    isAlive = _isAlive;
    isSpawned = _isSpawned;
    hp = _hp;
    

    _myMeshRenderer.enabled = isAlive && (!isLocalPlayer || isUsesMap);
    _myCollider.enabled = isAlive;
    _myRb.isKinematic = !isAlive;
}
```

Comment: а где она, сама переменная? или вы имете в виду поле? где само поле? как оно инициализируется? `[ClientRpc]` - вы логируете значение до того как его изменяете.

Comment: я иммею ввиду поле

Comment: в последнем методе он выводит true, а в инспекторе почему-то false